# Consolidar dados de várias abas numa só (mesma pasta de trabalho)

Tags: excel-vba

Tenho 18 planilhas(abas) com dados de usuários e preciso copiar e colar os dados em outra planilha(aba) de no nome consolidado. Preciso copiar o cabeçalho apenas da primeira planilha e ao final remover as linhas vazias.

Está tudo numa pasta de trabalho só. O cenário mais próximo que cheguei foi este mas está muito lento:

```
Sub juntarfim()
    '
    Range("A1").Select
    Sheets("PLANILHA1").Select
    Range("A5:E500").Select
    Application.CutCopyMode = False
    Selection.Copy
    Sheets("CONSOLIDADOJUNTOS").Select
    ActiveSheet.Paste
    '
    Range("A501").Select
    Sheets("PLANILHA2").Select
    Range("A6:E500").Select
    Application.CutCopyMode = False
    Selection.Copy
    Sheets("CONSOLIDADOJUNTOS").Select
    ActiveSheet.Paste
    '
End sub
```

Comment: Evite a utilização do [Select](https://stackoverflow.com/q/10714251/7690982), pois o mesmo é lento e pode causar erros em códigos muito grandes. Com relação ao código, se puder criar um [mcve] com alguns dados de exemplo...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Sub juntarfim()

Application.ScreenUpdating = False 'desativa atualização de tela.
Range("A1").Select
Sheets("PLANILHA1").Select
Range("A5:E500").Select
Application.CutCopyMode = False
Selection.Copy
Sheets("CONSOLIDADOJUNTOS").Select
ActiveSheet.Paste
'
Range("A501").Select
Sheets("PLANILHA2").Select
Range("A6:E500").Select
Application.CutCopyMode = False
Selection.Copy
Sheets("CONSOLIDADOJUNTOS").Select
ActiveSheet.Paste
'
End sub
```

Comment: muito obrigado!!!